# eclipse crashes on launch

Tags: java, eclipse

every time i want to launch eclipse i get this error:
eclipse quite unexpectedly:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c

VM Regions Near 0x3c:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100004000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a61b0c7 CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 39
1   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x000000010000306b findSymbol + 66
2   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x00000001000017f6 original_main + 1572
3   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001eb5 main + 1230
4   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001090 start + 52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ed17662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff88333421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff88333136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0xbd00a35079ee4aa0  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x6974696e49746573  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000608000029fc0  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbffb00  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff6d0
   r8: 0x000000000000000e   r9: 0x00007fff8a56d7f8  r10: 0x00007fff9218edfd  r11: 0x00007fff8a61b0a0
  r12: 0x00007fff75e75420  r13: 0x00006080000ac4e0  r14: 0x0000610000056980  r15: 0x0000608000029fc0
  rip: 0x00007fff8a61b0c7  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000000000003c

Logical CPU:     3
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

what should I do, it was working perfect yesterday ?

Comment: Perhaps try reinstalling eclipse or java.  Looks like something has been corrupted.

Comment: Try to run with `./eclipse -clean -refresh`

Comment: IMHO wrong site: Please try asking this on http://superuser.com

Comment: @AlexP when i try to run it from the terminal i get no such file or directory !

Comment: @user3648409 you need to change the directory where you put Eclipse and run from there. In addition may be the version you downloaded does not match your OS/architecture.

Comment: Have you seen this bugs (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390071 / https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431688)? There's an issue with installing/extracting packets on Mac.

Comment: @AlexP I don't think the version doesn't match my os because the eclipse was working fine yesterday, and when i copy it to the application i start get the error :)

Comment: @AlexP I'm facing the same issue, your command helps!

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue too, and later i realised that I didn't install all the contents to /Applications/eclipse. Never initiate the process by copying just the eclipse.app file into applications. That's what is making the app to crash.

You need to copy all of the contents found alongside Eclipse.app, like plugins/, features/, configuration/, etc

As a quick workaround, you can try invoking the app from where it had been unzipped.